# Could gravitational wave detectors be used for other purposes than gravitational wave detection?

Tags: gravitational-wave-detectors

Gravitational wave detectors like LIGO are very sensitive machines, and I wonder whether they could be (or actually are) used for other detections.  What comes into mind is:

- Earth science: The suspensions are supposed to filter out or dampen noise from outside the detector, and damping is often active.  This means that disturbances are monitored and automatically corrected, or are used to determine signal-to-noise ration for the GW detection. Hence there is additional information about the environment one could make use of.
- Material science: There are various kinds of these signal called *glitches* that sporadically occur and that do not look like they have been caused by gravitational waves.  To date, some(?) all(?) sources / causes of these glitches are unknown.  It could be crackle in the suspensions (due to stress etc.) or in the mirrors for example.  Could this be used like microphones to learn about materials? Nanophones, so to speak.

What I mean is that this additional benefit can be harvested during ordinary GW-detection and without decreasing quality of the GW detections.

Comment: One of the best uses is sparking public interest in physics.

Comment: I suppose it could be a very expensive, very sensitive seismograph.